# How to add Bootstrap 4 JS to use Modal with VueJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

I installed in my project bootstrap-vue from
  https://bootstrap-vue.js.org , because I use VueJS in the project. I'm new to vuejs so I don't know to much so far. 
I tried to add a bootstrap modal but didn't work. I knew that the bootstrap js is missing from my modules.

I put in my index.html the cdn from bootstrap and works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Project</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but this is an ugly solution.

```
<template>
<div>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

Does someone know how to use bootstrap js in vuejs with npm modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**. Run:

```
npm i jquery tether bootstrap --save-dev
```

**2**. Add the `ProvidePlugin` to the `plugins` array in both **build/webpack.dev.conf.js** and **build/webpack.prod.conf.js**

```
plugins: [ 
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'Tether': 'tether'
  })
]
```

**3**. Then:

```
npm i --save-dev expose-loader
```

Use in your entry point **main.js** like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
require('expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery!jquery')
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: Wow thanks, I've searched a while how to make it work without adding more external resources.

Comment: @JohnSmith please how may we apply this in this scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325537/how-to-use-bootstrap-4-themes-with-vuejs